# Java performing instance commands before static ones

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I ran into this problem, when an object uses a classes static instance, before it's even created. Example:

```
class Chair {
    public static Chair mychair = new Chair();
    public void foo() {}
}

class Table {
    public Table() {
        Chair.mychair.foo();
    }
}
```

So if I call the mychair.foo() , I get a NullPointerException. I know, not even static things get performed until the class is really needed. But how can I force Java to actually load the class, so it will be created?

Stacktrace of original program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at hu.intelligames.game.level.Level.<init>(Level.java:34)
    at hu.intelligames.game.Game.initialize(Game.java:64)
    at hu.intelligames.game.Game.<init>(Game.java:43)
    at hu.intelligames.game.Game.main(Game.java:80)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hu.intelligames.game.level.tiles.Tile.<clinit>(Tile.java:25)
    ... 4 more
```

Constructor of Level class (from line 25):

```
public Level(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        tiles = new Tile[width * height];

        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                tiles[i] = Tile.GRASS;
            else if (i % 3 == 1)
                tiles[i] = Tile.GRASS;
            else
                tiles[i] = Tile.STONE;
        }

        init();
    }
```

Whole code for Tile class:

```
public class Tile {

    public static Spritesheet tileSheet = new Spritesheet("/tiles.png");

    public static final Tile VOID = new Tile(0, 0, tileSheet, 0x00000000);
    public static final Tile GRASS = new Tile(1, 0, tileSheet, 0xff00ff00);
    public static final Tile STONE = new Tile(2, 0, tileSheet, 0xffaaaaaa);
    public static final Tile ROAD = new Tile(3, 0, tileSheet, 0xffabcdef);

    private Spritesheet sheet;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int colorCode;

    private static ArrayList<Tile> tileList;

    static {
        tileList.add(VOID);
        tileList.add(GRASS);
        tileList.add(STONE);
        tileList.add(ROAD);
    }

    public Tile(int x, int y, Spritesheet sheet, int colorCode) {
        this.sheet = sheet;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.colorCode = colorCode;
    }

    public void render(int xPos, int yPos, int xOff, int yOff, Screen screen) {
        screen.render(xPos, yPos, xOff, yOff, x, y, sheet);
    }

    public int getColorCode() {
        return colorCode;
    }

    public static Tile getTileByColorCode(int code) {
        for (Tile t : tileList) {
            if (t.getColorCode() == code) return t;
            break;
        }

        return VOID;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see it. Post compilable code and a stacktrace.

Comment: public static mychair?  Where is the assigned data type? (I see that the code has been edited now...)

Comment: Whoops, sorry, edited (I'm really tired...)

Comment: If you're trying to make a singleton, that isn't the way to do it.

Comment: Can you post a minimal runnable example throwing your exception? I have no exception running this code along with a Main class just calling `new Table()`.

Comment: No, not trying to make a singleton, I know how to do that. And why would it throw an exception?

Comment: Where is the `Level` class?  That seems to be important code to post, given that the exception occurs there.

Comment: That's not a NullPointerException. Something inside your Level initializer is throwing an exception.

Comment: Works fine. Must be s.th. else..m

Comment: Can you post line 25 of the `Tile` class (and its surroundings) instead? The posted code works fine...

Comment: Yes, the constructor of the Level uses these static pointers to objects.

Comment: Either post the real code of Tile and Game, so that we can explain the problem thanks to the stack trace, or post a self-contained example reproducing the problem. The posted code doesn't throw any exception if we call the Table constructor, and we can't guess the code that is actually executed.

Comment: @RuntimeException It seems that you have tried but have been caught!

Comment: Now show `Tile` static initializers...

Comment: Post the `Tile` static initialization code around line 25 please.

Comment: So you haven't initialized `private static ArrayList<Tile> tileList;` and then ask why it's `null`.  You made us go through all that...Please show some effort next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static ArrayList<Tile> tileList;
```

Remains null

```
static {
    tileList = new ArrayList<>();
    tileList.add(VOID);
    tileList.add(GRASS);
    tileList.add(STONE);
    tileList.add(ROAD);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your field `tileList` is not initialized, so the static initialization code throws NPE.

This should do the trick:

```
private static ArrayList<Tile> tileList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Next time, just read your stack trace :D It literally says *you're trying to dereference null at line 25 of file Tile.java*